# Removing stencil mask from chip for BGA reballing

Tags: bga, stencil

I am in the process of reballing my ps3 system. This is my very first time so i am watching tutorials online.

My question is how do i remove the stencil mask from the chip without moving the balls?

If you take a look at this video [youtube_vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3N3PEIYPXk) at 6:20, it shows the guy pouring balls into the stencil mask, but the next frames show the chip without the stencil mask and the balls are still on it. So how did he remove the stencil mask without moving the balls?

I also have a station where you put your chip and it says there, then a big stencil mask gets screwed, but i have very little stencil masks and i cannot screw them. So i have to do like this guy is doing

Comment: *"If you take a look at this video"* .... what video?

Comment: youtube has a comment function... if you want to know how someone did something, you might want to ask them instead of asking other strangers to guess how somoene did something we can not see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flux or solder paste applied should hold the balls in place.  After that it's heated so the balls melt to the pads on the underside of the bga.  IPC 7711 contains a good process to follow.  Here's a [link](https://pcbrework.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/ipc-7711-procedure-5-7-6-bgacsp-reballing/) to someone giving better info than that video.